# Sort first n Number of data in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 100000 document in index of elasticsearch but I would like to get 25 records that are sorted based on first 20000 documents, not all 100000. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "sorted based on first X documents and not all"? Wouldn't you have to sort all the documents in order to obtain the first X documents?

Comment: No I don't want to sort all the document for find first X. I would like to short first N records out of N+100 to get first 25 Records

Comment: when you say first N out of first N+100, how do you find out what the first N are?

Comment: I can use incremental document ID to check first N Records